# How to fit a rectangle into a space (get relative camera position) having its dimentions and shape?

Tags: image, algorithm, camera

Say we have a web cam image of a road. We have picked 4 connected 2d lines of a rectangle, and we know there are 90deg angles between them. We have set their real life dimentions. How one can get 3d camera position relative to that rectangle from such data?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having 4 pairs of corresponding coordinates - real word ones and coordinates at camera matrix (in photo image coordinate system), one can calcalate matrix of perspective transformation, for example, with OpenCV function [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae).

Then apply [decomposeProjectionMatrix](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gaaae5a7899faa1ffdf268cd9088940248)

If you are using another means/libraries for image acquisition/treatment, they might contain something similar

Comment: So if we do not know pairs - only sides sizes we can set coordinate pairs. And thus having something like `(0, 0, 0):(x1, y1); (0,0,w):(x2, y2); (0, 0, h):(x3, y3); (w,0,h) : (x4, y4)` what would be the `src` and `dst` of  `getPerspectiveTransform`?

Comment: getPerspectiveTransform considers mapping of some 2d plane to 2d, so remove 3-rd coordinate (Y here) to make src