# Having a point from 3 static cameras prespectives how to restore its position in 3d space?

Tags: image, algorithm, opencv, camera

We have same [rectangle position relative to 3 same type of staticly installed web cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951678/how-to-fit-a-rectangle-into-a-space-get-relative-camera-position-having-its-di) that are not on the same line. Say on a flat basketball field. Thus we have tham all inside one 3d space and `(x, y, z); (ax, ay, az);` positionas and orientations set for all of them.

We have a ball color and we found its position on all 3 images `im1, im2, im3`. Now having its position on 2d frames `(p1x, p1y);(p2x, p2y);(p3x, p3y)`, and cameras pos\orientations how to get ball position in 3d space?

Comment: You could try casting a ray from behind the cameras (the distance would have to be calibrated) "though" the ball on the screen. Then [find the closest points between the lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993953/closest-points-between-two-lines), since the rays likely won't be exact enough to intersect. That link only shows how to do it for two lines, but you could probably repeat between each pair of two and then average the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to *unproject* 2D screen coordinates into 3D coordinates in space.
2. You need to solve system of equation to find real point in 3D from 3 rays you got on the first step.

You can find source code for `gluUnProject` [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code). I also provide here my code for it:

```cs
public Vector4 Unproject(float x, float y, Matrix4 View)
{
    var ndcX = x / Viewport.Width * 2 - 1.0f;
    var ndcY = y / Viewport.Height * 2 - 1.0f;
    var invVP = Matrix4.Invert(View * ProjectionMatrix);
    // We don't z-coordinate of the point, so we choose 0.0f for it.
    // We are going to find out it later.
    var screenPos = new Vector4(ndcX, -ndcY, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    var res = Vector4.Transform(screenPos, invVP);
    return res / res.W;
}

Vector3 ComputeRay(Camera camera, Vector2 p)
{
    var worldPos = Unproject(p.X, p.Y, camera.View);
    var dir = new Vector3(worldPos) - camera.Eye;
    return new Ray(camera.Eye, Vector3.Normalize(dir));
}
```

Now you need to find intersection of three such rays. Theoretically that would be enough to use only two rays. It depends on positions of your cameras.

If we had infinite precision floating point arithmetic and input was without noise that would be trivial. But in reality you might need to exploit some simple numerical scheme to find the point with an appropriate precision.

Comment: You would also need infinitely exact measurements of camera position and orientation, absolutely linear projection optics onto the image frame and infinite pixel density of the camera image. It is not only the computation that introduces errors, it can also not be more precise than the inputs are.

Comment: @LutzL I agree, noise is everywhere.

Comment: @LutzL But probably, in the world of infinite precision arithmetic we would also have infinitely exact measurements and so on))

Comment: And we would have infinite clock rates on our computers to handle these infinitely long numbers instantly, and that without any radiation losses because all processor structures would be infinitely small. If only physics was not so atomar and quantum.

Comment: Not having infinit precision, and having some unknown lense focus distortion, and having cameras not oriented on a plane (rotated in different angles what would you recommend to change?

Comment: @DuckQueen first i would find rays from cameras as explained in my answer. Then, for every pair of rays i would find [this point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993953/closest-points-between-two-lines). And then take the mean of these three points. Of course, there will be some error , but you can't get your result better than your measurements.